# VBE BDF font rendering

Tags: c++, kernel

I'm working on a hobby kernel, with graphics and rendering fonts. The font format is BDF. Some of them (like for Ubuntu Mono) I used was ttf2bdf. Then I use a program called bdf2c which converts it to a .c file. From there, I can use the data in my program.

First, let me start off by showing you code that won't change, but will help you understand the rest of the program:

#### Exposition; don't review

> **multiboot.h**
>
> ```
> struct multiboot_info
> {
>  /* irrelevant stuff */
>
>  /* Video */
>  multiboot_uint32_t vbe_control_info;
>  multiboot_uint32_t vbe_mode_info;
>  multiboot_uint16_t vbe_mode;
>  multiboot_uint16_t vbe_interface_seg;
>  multiboot_uint16_t vbe_interface_off;
>  multiboot_uint16_t vbe_interface_len;
> };
> typedef struct multiboot_info multiboot_info_t;
>
> struct vbe_mode_info 
> {
>   uint16_t attributes;
>   uint8_t  winA,winB;
>   uint16_t granularity;
>   uint16_t winsize;
>   uint16_t segmentA, segmentB;
>   uint32_t winFuncPtr; // ptr to INT 0x10 Function 0x4F05
>   uint16_t pitch; // bytes per scanline
>
>   uint16_t Xres, Yres;
>   uint8_t  Wchar, Ychar, planes, bpp, banks;
>   uint8_t  memory_model, bank_size, image_pages;
>   uint8_t  reserved0;
>
>   uint8_t  red_mask_size, red_position;
>   uint8_t  green_mask_size, green_position;
>   uint8_t  blue_mask_size, blue_position;
>   uint8_t  rsv_mask, rsv_position;
>   uint8_t  directcolor_attributes;
>
>   uint32_t physbase;  // your LFB (Linear Framebuffer) address ;)
>   uint32_t reserved1;
>   uint16_t reserved2;
>
>   // VBE 3.0, use these if LFB is present
>   uint16_t LinBytesPerScanLine;
>   uint8_t  BnkNumberofImagePages;
>   uint8_t  LinNumberofImagePages;
>   uint8_t  LinRedMaskSize;
>   uint8_t  LinRedFieldPosition;
>   uint8_t  LinGreenMaskSize;
>   uint8_t  LinGreenFieldPosition;
>   uint8_t  LinBlueMaskSize;
>   uint8_t  LinBlueMaskPosition;
>   uint8_t  LinRsvdMaskSize;
>   uint8_t  LinRsvdFieldPosition;
>   uint32_t MaxPixelClock;
>   uint8_t  Reserved;
> };
> typedef struct vbe_mode_info vbe_mode_info_t;
> ```
>
> GRUB fills in the proper information to the header, so there's no code
>   to show for that.
>
> **font.h**
>
> ```
>   /// bitmap font structure
> struct bitmap_font {
>   unsigned char Width;        ///< max. character width
>   unsigned char Height;       ///< character height
>   unsigned short Chars;       ///< number of characters in font
>   const unsigned char *Widths;    ///< width of each character
>   const unsigned short *Index;    ///< encoding to character index
>   const unsigned char *Bitmap;    ///< bitmap of all characters
> };
>
> // masking defines omitted
> ```
>
> **font.c**
>
> ```
>   /// bitmap font structure
> const struct bitmap_font font = {
>   .Width = 17, .Height = 18,
>   .Chars = 1224,
>   .Widths = __font_widths__,
>   .Index = __font_index__,
>   .Bitmap = __font_bitmap__,
> };
> ```
>
> And an example of what a glyph looks like:
>
> ```
> //  33 $21 '0021'
> //    width 9, bbx 3, bby 0, bbw 2, bbh 11
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ________,________,________,
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ___XX___,________,________,
>   ________,________,________,
>   ________,________,________,
>   ________,________,________,
>   ________,________,________,
>   ________,________,________,
>   ________,________,________,
>   ________,________,________,
> ```

#### Review this

Now for the actual kernel code. I'm trying to write as much C++ code as possible and avoid C code. That doesn't make my C++ code any less C-ish, but I'm uncomfortable writing in C. Let's start with the helper functions:

**cpplib.hpp**

```
#ifndef CPPLIB_
#define CPPLIB_

template< class T > struct remove_reference      {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_reference<T&>  {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_reference<T&&> {typedef T type;};

template<class _Ty> inline
typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&&
move(_Ty&& _Arg)
{   // forward _Arg as movable
    return ((typename remove_reference<_Ty>::type&&)_Arg);
}

template<typename T> void swap(T& t1, T& t2) {
    T temp = move(t1); // or T temp(move(t1));
    t1 = move(t2);
    t2 = move(temp);
}

template<class ForwardIt1, class ForwardIt2>
void iter_swap(ForwardIt1 a, ForwardIt2 b)
{
   swap(*a, *b);
}

template<class BidirIt>
void reverse(BidirIt first, BidirIt last)
{
    while ((first != last) && (first != --last)) {
        iter_swap(first++, last);
    }
}

template<class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
InputIt find_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        if (p(*first)) {
            return first;
        }
    }
    return last;
}

template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
bool any_of(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    return find_if(first, last, p) != last;
}

bool islower(wchar_t c)
{
    static const wchar_t *lowercase = L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return any_of(lowercase, lowercase + 26, [&] (wchar_t c2) -> bool { return c == c2; });
}

template <typename Iter, typename T>
size_t index_of(Iter first, Iter last, const T& x)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while (first != last && *first != x)
      ++first, ++i;
    return i;
}

#endif
```

`<iterator>` is not implemented, so for all intents and purposes everything is assumed to be a random access iterator. `index_of` is used later to search the font indexes array to map a given char to its place in the array.

**main.cpp**

```
#define CHECK_BIT(var,pos) ((var) & (1<<(pos)))

vbe_mode_info_t *vbe;
uint8_t *mem;

// 24bpp
void draw_pixel(int x, int y, uint32_t color)
{
    auto pos = y * vbe->LinBytesPerScanLine + x * (vbe->bpp / 8);
    mem[pos] = color & 0xFF;
    mem[pos + 1] = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    mem[pos + 2] = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
}

void draw_rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, uint32_t color)
{
    for (int i = x; i < x + width; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = y; j < y + height; ++j)
        {
            draw_pixel(i, j, color);
        }
    }
}

extern bitmap_font font;

struct FontSettings
{
    const size_t font_index_size;
    const size_t glyph_height;
    const size_t glyph_width;
    const size_t letter_spacing;
    const size_t num_columns;
    const size_t offset_kerning;
};

const FontSettings UbuntuMonoSettings{1224, 17, 8, 4, 3, 7};
const FontSettings GohuFontSettings  {1597, 10, 8, 0, 1, 3};
const FontSettings MechaSettings     {193,  16, 14, 0, 2, 5};

FontSettings currentFont = MechaSettings;

int get_yoffset(wchar_t c)
{
    int cx, cy;
    const unsigned char *glyph = font.Bitmap + 
        (index_of(font.Index, font.Index + currentFont.font_index_size, (int)c)) 
            * ((currentFont.glyph_height + 1) * currentFont.num_columns);

    int offset = 0;
    bool quit = false;
    for (cy = currentFont.glyph_height; cy > 0; cy--) 
    {
        for (cx = 0; cx < currentFont.glyph_width * currentFont.num_columns; cx++) 
        {
            // 1 << x = powers of 2
            // glyph_height - cx because the glyph is backwards
            if (glyph[cy * currentFont.num_columns] 
                & (1 << (currentFont.glyph_height - cx)))
            {
                quit = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (quit)
            return offset;
        ++offset;
    }
    return offset;
}

void drawchar(wchar_t c, int x, int y, int fgcolor, int bgcolor = -1)
{
    int cx, cy;
    const unsigned char *glyph = font.Bitmap + 
        (index_of(font.Index, font.Index + currentFont.font_index_size, (int)c)) 
            * ((currentFont.glyph_height + 1) * currentFont.num_columns);

    for (cy = 0; cy <= currentFont.glyph_height; cy++) 
    {
        for (cx = 0; cx < currentFont.glyph_width * currentFont.num_columns; cx++) 
        {
            // 1 << x = powers of 2
            // glyph_height - cx because the glyph is backwards
            if (glyph[cy * currentFont.num_columns] 
                & (1 << (currentFont.glyph_height - cx)))
            {
                draw_pixel(x + cx, y + cy, fgcolor);
            } else {
                // unimplemented: background color
            }
        }
    }
}

void draw_string(const wchar_t *s, int x, int y, int fgcolor, int bgcolor = -1) 
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    int xoffset = 0;
    int yoffset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (s[i] == '\n') 
        {
            y += currentFont.glyph_height;
            xoffset = 0;
        }

        if (islower(s[i]))
        {
            yoffset = get_yoffset(s[i]) - currentFont.offset_kerning;
        }

        drawchar(s[i], x + xoffset * (currentFont.glyph_width + currentFont.letter_spacing), 
            y + yoffset, fgcolor, bgcolor);
        ++xoffset;        
    }
}

const wchar_t *doge = LR"doge(░░░░░░░░░▄░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▄
░░░░░░░░▌▒█░░░░░░░░░░░▄▀▒▌
░░░░░░░░▌▒▒█░░░░░░░░▄▀▒▒▒▐
░░░░░░░▐▄▀▒▒▀▀▀▀▄▄▄▀▒▒▒▒▒▐
░░░░░▄▄▀▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒▒▄█▒▐
░░░▄▀▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▀██▀▒▌
░░▐▒▒▒▄▄▒▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▀▄▒▒▌
░░▌░░▌█▀▒▒▒▒▒▄▀█▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█▒▐
░▐░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▌██▀▒▒░░░▒▒▒▀▄▌
░▌░▒▄██▄▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▌
▀▒▀▐▄█▄█▌▄░▀▒▒░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒
)doge";

extern "C" void kernel_main(uint32_t magic, uint32_t addr)  {
    multiboot_info_t *mbi = (multiboot_info_t *)addr;
    vbe = (vbe_mode_info_t *)mbi->vbe_mode_info;
    printf("attributes: %u\nwinA: %u\nwinB: %u\ngranularity: %u\nwinsize: %u\nsegmentA: %x\nsegmentB: %x\nwinFuncPtr: %x\npitch: %u\nXres: %u\nYres: %u\nWchar: %u\nYchar: %u\nplanes: %u\nbpp: %u\nbanks: %u\nmemory_model: %u\nbank_size: %u\nimage_pages: %u\nreserved0: %u\nred_mask_size: %u\nred_position: %u\ngreen_mask_size: %u\ngreen_position: %u\nblue_mask_size: %u\nblue_position: %u\nrsv_mask: %u\nrsv_position: %u\ndirectcolor_attributes: %u\nphysbase: %x\nreserved1: %u\nreserved2: %u\nLinBytesPerScanLine: %u\nBnkNumberofImagePages: %u\nLinNumberofImagePages: %u\nLinRedMaskSize: %u\nLinRedFieldPosition: %u\nLinGreenMaskSize: %u\nLinGreenFieldPosition: %u\nLinBlueMaskSize: %u\nLinBlueMaskPosition: %u\nLinRsvdMaskSize: %u\nLinRsvdFieldPosition: %u\nMaxPixelClock: %u\nReserved: %u", vbe->attributes,vbe->winA,vbe->winB,vbe->granularity,vbe->winsize,vbe->segmentA,vbe->segmentB,vbe->winFuncPtr,vbe->pitch,vbe->Xres,vbe->Yres,vbe->Wchar,vbe->Ychar,vbe->planes,vbe->bpp,vbe->banks,vbe->memory_model,vbe->bank_size,vbe->image_pages,vbe->reserved0,vbe->red_mask_size,vbe->red_position,vbe->green_mask_size,vbe->green_position,vbe->blue_mask_size,vbe->blue_position,vbe->rsv_mask,vbe->rsv_position,vbe->directcolor_attributes,vbe->physbase,vbe->reserved1,vbe->reserved2,vbe->LinBytesPerScanLine,vbe->BnkNumberofImagePages,vbe->LinNumberofImagePages,vbe->LinRedMaskSize,vbe->LinRedFieldPosition,vbe->LinGreenMaskSize,vbe->LinGreenFieldPosition,vbe->LinBlueMaskSize,vbe->LinBlueMaskPosition,vbe->LinRsvdMaskSize,vbe->LinRsvdFieldPosition,vbe->MaxPixelClock,vbe->Reserved);
    uint16_t uses_lfb = CHECK_BIT(mbi->vbe_mode, 14);
    if (uses_lfb)
        write_serial_string("uses LFB");

    mem = (uint8_t *)vbe->physbase;

    /*int32_t colors[] = {
        0xFFFFFF, 0xC0C0C0, 0x808080,
        0x000000, 0xFF0000, 0x800000,
        0xFFFF00, 0x808000, 0x00FF00,
        0x008000, 0x00FFFF, 0x008080,
        0x0000FF, 0x000080, 0xFF00FF,
        0x800080
    };
    int idx = 0;
    int chunk_size = 8;
    int xchunk = (vbe->Xres / chunk_size);
    int ychunk = (vbe->Yres / chunk_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < chunk_size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < chunk_size; ++j)
        {
            draw_rectangle(j * xchunk, i * ychunk, xchunk, ychunk, 
                colors[idx]);
            if (++idx == 16)
                idx = 0;
        }
    }*/
    draw_string(L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 0, 0, 0xFFFFFFF);
    draw_string(L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 0, currentFont.glyph_height, 0xFFFFFFF);
    draw_string(L"!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ", 0, currentFont.glyph_height * 2, 0xFFFFFF);
    draw_string(L"0123456789", 0, currentFont.glyph_height * 3, 0xFFFFFF);
    draw_string(L"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", 0, currentFont.glyph_height * 4, 0xFFFFFF);
    draw_string(doge, 0, currentFont.glyph_height * 5, 0xFFFFFF);
}
```

`write_serial_string` is an irrevelant debug function (it writes to the COM1 port, which is redirected to a file via my emulator.)

Now for my questions:

- How do I make my font handling more generic? I rely too much on hard-coded values, and I strongly suspect there's several off-by-one errors. While Ubuntu Mono and Gohu Font work just fine, Mecha is slightly buggy, which means my code is not as generic as I thought.
- How do I reduce code duplication? There's two sources of code duplication:

  - Function overloads for library functions (like `strlen`) that need to handle both `char` and `wchar_t`
  - Algorithms that are very similar but perform different purposes: i.e, getting the offset or printing
- Can I improve readability? There's a compromise between terseness and verbosity: or usability vs. readability. Simply changing variable and function names isn't enough, how can the code be refactored? That ugly `printf`.
- Any comments on API, separation of library and kernel code, etc.